# Can you access table constraints with db_datareader role membership in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out why a particular SQL Server database user that has `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` membership, can't run a select statement that gets some check constraints on a particular table.

I run the select statement in my code, but it doesn't return any data. I thought maybe that in order to get constraint information, you might need different permissions. I've tried going out to look at some of the roles, and what they mean, but it's not clear what exactly the db_reader role can do.

```
string constraintCommand = @"SELECT tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME, CC.CHECK_CLAUSE
    FROM[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CHECK_CONSTRAINTS as cc
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc ON cc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND cc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME = 'VideoSources'";
```

This is in C#. I run the SQL statement in SSMS as me (`db_owner`), and the SQL statement returns the data I need. I'm wondering if it's a permission problem of some sort.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416362/sql-server-2008-grant-permission-to-information-schema-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 grant permission to information\_schema.columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416362/sql-server-2008-grant-permission-to-information-schema-columns)

Comment: Running the grant view definition on that user for the database in question work.  I ran:  USE [My database name]; GO; GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO theDataBaseUser

Answer (score 1):

To run a stored procedure the role needs Execute permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that permission Grant or Deny overrides the role membership. You may have to specifically Grant Select permission in the table.